# Recycler View is inconsistently showing/not showing data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

The recycler view sometimes show or not show the data when I start the activity. This is how it's programmed, I have a main activity and an activity that has a recycler view in it. To test it I hardcoded a data using a for loop in the onCreate method. It will only loop and add data to the array before it is set to the recycler view. Now the problem is that, sometimes the data shows up and sometimes there's nothing in the list. I can easily reproduce the issue by going back and fort to the main activity and the activity with recycler view. I think I'm doing it wrong by adding it to the onCreate.

Here's what I have in the onCreate:

```
    for(i in 1..5){
        val newDeliveredAsset = AssetDelivered()
        newDeliveredAsset.id = i
        newDeliveredAsset.accountNumber = 1
        newDeliveredAsset.barCode = "BB" + i.toString()
        newDeliveredAsset.description = "test " + i.toString()

        assets.add(newDeliveredAsset)
    }

    rvAsset = findViewById(R.id.ce_recycler_view)
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    layoutManager.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
    rvAsset.layoutManager = layoutManager

    rvAdapter = AssetRecyclerViewAdapter(this, assets as List<Asset>)
    rvAsset.adapter = rvAdapter
```

I also tried to log the getItemSize of the adapter and it shows the correct number.

Update: Left the phone on the activity that's not showing the recycler view items. After few minutes, the items showed up.

Comment: There's nothing in the code you've shown us that indicates that something is wrong. Are you manipulating the data somewhere else in your `Activity`?

Comment: The only data I'm using is hardcoded within the for loop. There's nothing else in the code that the data is being manipulated. I'll create a github repo that easily reproduce the issue.

Comment: Fixed the problem, it's not related to the recycler view after all. It's happening because of the AppBarLayout that I placed at the bottom of the screen. I replaced that AppBarLayout with a frame layout.